# How can I declare NSAttributedStringKey.font for custom font?

Tags: swift

I want to calculate the height of the text to get the estimated height for the collection view cell. I use the following code inside `collectionViewLayout` function;

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

    if let messageText = messages[indexPath.row]?.text {

        let size = CGSize(width: view.frame.width, height: 1000)
        let options = NSStringDrawingOptions.usesFontLeading.union(.usesLineFragmentOrigin)
        let estimatedFrame = NSString(string: messageText).boundingRect(with: size, options: options, attributes: [NSAttributedStringKey.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 17)], context: nil)
        return CGSize(width: view.frame.width, height: estimatedFrame.height + 20)
    }

    return CGSize(width: view.frame.width, height: 100)
}
```

This is working for system fonts, but not for my custom font inside my project. The problem is that the estimatedFrame is not equal to the result with a system font. I think the problem will be the param of options: `attributes`. Is there a way like `UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 17)` for custom fonts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I'm reading your question right, you want:

```
UIFont(name: "yourCustomFontNameString", size: 17)
```

So:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

    if let messageText = messages[indexPath.row]?.text {

        let size = CGSize(width: view.frame.width, height: 1000)
        let options = NSStringDrawingOptions.usesFontLeading.union(.usesLineFragmentOrigin)
        let estimatedFrame = NSString(string: messageText).boundingRect(with: size, options: options, attributes: [NSAttributedStringKey.font: UIFont(name: "yourCustomFontNameString", size: 17)], context: nil)
        return CGSize(width: view.frame.width, height: estimatedFrame.height + 20)
    }

    return CGSize(width: view.frame.width, height: 100)
}
```

Comment: This will throw an error:` Argument labels '(name:, ofSize:)' do not match any available overloads` Of course I changed the string name to my Font name.

Comment: Yes, fonts are loaded correctly, only when I implement above snippet, it will throw the error of `Argument labels '(name:, ofSize:)`

Comment: Oh, silly me - it's a compile error not a runtime error. `size` not `ofSize` - they changed it for Swift 4 (possibly 3).

Comment: You may also need to force unwrap it: `UIFont(name: "yourCustomFontNameString", size: 17)!`